# How to handle Sets with Generics

Tags: delphi, generics

I am trying to convert a set of Bytes to an enumerated set using Generics. But the code does not compile. TValue.FromOrdinal(TypeInfo(T), Ord(B)).AsType does actually correctly return the enumerated value  but I cannot include this value in the enumerated set.

```
interface 

type TByteSet = set of Byte;
type TMyNewEnum = (meZero, meOne, meTwo);
type TMyNewEnumSet = set of TMyNewEnum;

type
  TEnum<T> = class(TObject)
  public
    class function ToString(const aEnumValue: T): string; reintroduce;
    class function FromString(const aEnumString: string; const aDefault: T): T;
    class procedure FromByteSet(const Value: TByteSet; out EnumSet: TMyNewEnumSet);
  end

  implementation
Var
  MyByteSet: TMyByteSet;
  MyEnumSet: TMyNewEnumSet;
...  
class procedure TEnum<T>.FromByteSet(const Value: TByteSet; out EnumSet: TMyNewEnumSet);
var
  B: Byte;
begin
  Assert(PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T)).Kind = tkEnumeration, 'Type parameter must be an Enumeration');
  for B in Value do
    begin
      EnumSet := EnumSet + TValue.FromOrdinal(TypeInfo(T), Ord(B)).AsType<T>; //This line does not compile
    end;
end;
...



//intended Usage
  MyByteSet := [0, 2];
  TEnum<TMyNewEnum>.FromByteSet(MyByteSet, MyEnumSet); 
  //I would like MyEnumSet to contain [meZero, meTwo]

end.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using generics if you know you want to return a TmyNewEnumSet? Then you can get rid of TValue and simply cast. So I assume this is not really what you want. You want to return a T, right? But even then, what you want can not be done in a generic way. See David's answer which tells you why. If you really want to return a TMyNewEnumSet, you can probably simply **cast**, i.e. `EnumSet := TMyNewEnumSet(Byte(ByteSet));`(untested, can't check this here).

Comment: What I ultimately want is to return a generic Set (in the above example the out parameter - TMyNewEnumSet) containing the individual enumerated contents.  I was hoping that this interim step would lead me there.

Comment: My answer explains why there is no such thing as a generic set in the current Delphi language. I think we are done therefore.

Comment: You could follow the example of `TList<T>`, which uses the new intrinsics to call the appropriate helper function, depending on `T`. You could simply refuse to handle anything but `tkEnumeration`, and if `T`is a `tkEnumeration`, resolve this with a low level byte packing code, returning the right bit pattern. You could use untyped var or const parameters for that. Declare the "return" value as untyped out or var.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want quite simply, but not the way you are trying to do it (which has been pointed out by others)

If you step through the following program you will see in the debugger that MyEnumSet ends up with the desired value.

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;


type TByteSet = set of Byte;
type TMyNewEnum = (meZero, meOne, meTwo);
type TMyNewEnumSet = set of TMyNewEnum;

type
  TEnum<T> = class(TObject)
  public
    class procedure FromByteSet(const Value: TByteSet; out EnumSet: T);
  end;

Var
  MyByteSet: TByteSet;
  MyEnumSet: TMyNewEnumSet;


procedure Test( const Parm1 : TByteSet; out Parm2 : TMyNewEnumSet );
var
  iResult : TMyNewEnumSet absolute Parm1;
begin
  Parm2 := iResult;
end;


{ TEnum<T> }

class procedure TEnum<T>.FromByteSet(const Value: TByteSet; out EnumSet : T );
var
  iResult : T absolute Value;
begin
  EnumSet := iResult;
end;

begin
  MyByteSet := [0,2];
  TEnum<TMyNewEnumSet>.FromByteSet( MyByteSet, MyEnumSet);
end.
```

Of course, you will need to add error checking (bounds and so on) for which you can use RTTI.

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting is not possible. For it to be possible, you would need to be able to constrain the generic type parameter to be a type over which a set can be formed. But no such generic constraint is supported by the language.

In fact your existing code already contains the tell-tale signs of the root problem. You have:

```
type
  TEnum<T> = class(TObject)
  public
    class procedure FromByteSet(const Value: TByteSet; out EnumSet: TMyNewEnumSet);
  end;
```

The elephant in the room here is that `FromByteSet` makes no reference to `T` and so is not generic.

In order to make the function generic you would need something like this:

```
type
  TEnum<T: record> = class(TObject)
  private
    type SetOfT = set of T;
  public
    class procedure FromByteSet(const Value: TByteSet; out EnumSet: SetOfT);
  end;
```

This does not compile. The compiler objects to the type declaration with:

```
[dcc32 Error]: E2001 Ordinal type required
```

That's because the compiler cannot be sure that `T` is an ordinal type. In order for it to do so, because `T` is a generic type parameter, you would need there to impose a generic constraint that `T` was an ordinal type. But the language supports no such constraint.